# Show that there exists a $C > 0$ such that $c_n < C\sqrt{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

This is a practice problem for a PhD prelim.

For $x$ in $[-1,1]$, define $P_n(x) = c_n(1-x^2)^n$, where $c_n$ is such that $\int_{-1}^{1}P_n =1$.

(i) Show that there is a positive constant $C$ such that $c_n \leq C\sqrt{n}$.

(ii) Let $f$ be a real- valued continuous function on $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Set $f_n(x) = \int_0^1P_n(x-t)f(t)dt$. Show that $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly.

I'm pretty stuck on this, so a hint on how to get started would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**For part (i)**

Use the normalization property of $P_n$
$$
1=\int_{-1}^1 P_n(x) dx
\\
\implies c_n = \left( \int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^n dx \right)^{-1}
= \frac{\Gamma(n+\frac{3}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi} \,\Gamma(n+1)} \,.
$$
There is an asymptotic approximation ([wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General))
$$
\lim_n \frac{\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(n) \sqrt{n}} = 1
$$
which can be used to get the result for part (i).

**For part (ii)**

Here you need to show that
$$
\forall \epsilon \exists N \forall n>N, x: \quad |f_n(x)-f(x)|< \epsilon \,.
$$

Now use
$$
\begin{align}
  |f_n(x)-f(x)|^2
  & = \left( \int_0^1 \left( P_n(x-t) f(t) -f(x) \right) dt \right)^2
  \\
  & = \left( \int_{-1}^1 \left( P_n(s) f(x-s) \mathbb{1}_x(s) - P_n(s) f(x) \right) ds \right)^2
  \\
  & = \left( \int_{-1}^1 P_n(s) \left(f(x-s) \mathbb{1}_x(s) -f(x) \right) ds \right)^2
  \\
  & \leq \left( \int_{-1}^1 P_n^2 \right) \left( \int_{-1}^1 \left|f(x-s) \mathbb{1}_x(s) -f(x) \right|^2 ds \right)\,.
\end{align}
$$
Where I have defined this identiy function $\mathbb{1}_x(s) := \begin{cases}1 & s \in (x-1,x) \\ 0 & \text{else}\end{cases}$.
The inequality is standard Cauchy-Schwartz.

Note that the second factor can be approximated by a constant ($f$ is continuous).
The first factor converges to 0 by the help of part (i).